# Php, удалить из строчки все лишнее

Tags: php

/upl/img/2jf-img1.webp?id=2335

Как удалить из строчки все и оставить только img1.webp

То есть "2jf-" может не быть, а может и есть равно как из все то что за знаком "?"

Comment: Регуляркой? Ну или в край эксплодом=)

Comment: Не удается составить регулярку, только так

Comment: preg_match('~/+\d*\K[^\v/?#]++(?![\d/])~m', $data['imgpr'], $nameimg);
$nameimg[0]

Comment: Так вытаскиваем все в массив. Как будет верно, именно удалить и сразу на выходе получить готовый результат, не в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~(?:.*-)?([^/]+?)(?:\?.*)?$~', '$1', $str);
```

Результаты:

```
/upl/img/2jf-img1.webp?id=2335 -> img1.webp
/upl/img/user/2/2jf-img1.webp?id=2335 -> img1.webp
/upl/assets/img1.webp?id=2335 -> img1.webp
/im1.jpg -> im1.jpg
/im1.jpg? -> im1.jpg
/im1.jpg?id=xxx -> im1.jpg
/xyz-im1.jpg?id=xxx -> im1.jpg
-im1.jpg?id=xxx -> im1.jpg
```

Comment: А если будет более длинный путь?=))

Comment: Ну или в целом неизвестное количество вложенных директорий

Comment: Количество директорий может быть больше... Под preg_replace соствить регулярку, было бы здорового. И удалить 2jf- и все что за знаком "?"

Comment: Так же 2jf-, может не быть. В основном рассчитываю присваивать, это возможно 3jfsiv-, либо 24-. Ориентировочно, при наличии дефиса, удалять и дифис и все что до него.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов обновлено

Answer (score 0):

Если 2jf- может не быть, но обязательное, если есть, то

```
$name = basename(parse_url('/upl/img/2jf-img1.webp?id=2335')['path']);
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто порезать `explode`:

```
function foo($src) {
    $res = explode('?', $src)[0];
    $res = explode('/', $res);
    $res = array_pop($res);
    $res = explode('-', $res);
    $res = array_pop($res);
    return $res;    
}


echo foo('/upl/img/2jf-img1.webp?id=2335'), PHP_EOL;
echo foo('/upl/img/img1.webp?id=2335'), PHP_EOL;
echo foo('/upl/img/2jf-img1.webp'), PHP_EOL;
echo foo('/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/img1.webp'), PHP_EOL;
```

Можно регуляным выражением:

```
function foo($src) {
    preg_match('#([^-/\?]+)(?:\?.*|$)#', $src, $m);
    return $m ? $m[1] : '';
}
```

parse_url:

```
function foo($src) {
    $res = basename(parse_url($src)['path']);
    $res = explode('-', $res);
    $res = array_pop($res);
    return $res;    
}
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/6JN4O)